# Relating Euler class to other characteristic classes

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

If I understand correctly, given a complex vector bundle $\pi:E \to X$, its Euler class $e(E)$ is given by $$e(E)=c_k(E)$$ for $k \in \text{min}\{\text{Rank}(E), \text{dim}(X)\}.$

Do we have similar results for other bundles?
Say:

1) Real vector bundle?

2) Projective bundle (a fiber bundle whose fibers are projective spaces):

i) Real projective bundle?

ii) Complex projective bundle?

iii) Quaternion projective bundle?

(needed to be oriented.)

Comment: e.g. If the rank ''r'' is even, then the cohomology class $e(E) \cup e(E)$ equals the top Pontryagin class $p_{r/2}(E)$.

Comment: Do you have some reference for that statement? @wonderich It will help me a lot

Comment: Your first statement is wrong -- $e(E)$ is always equal to $c_k(E)$ where $k=\text{Rank}(E)$.